# Training loss is always decreasing

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, gradient, training-data, loss-function

I am training PyTorch model for binary classification and my input vector of length 561 [341 is one hot encoding] and the others are features between 0 and 1. my output is [0,1] or [1,0] . My issue is that the training loss is always decrease i tried to try more epochs until 200 but nothing change, I am wondering if I am calculating the loss in wrong way, sometimes training loss is decreasing and test loss is decrease and increase.

Here is my model, I also tried different models with lstm and cnn and the loss always decreasing

```
class MyRegression(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, output_dim):
        super(MyRegression, self).__init__()
        # One layer
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(input_dim, 128)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(128, output_dim)
    def forward(self, x):
        return self.linear2(self.linear1(x))
```

and the training function

```
def run_gradient_descent(model, data_train, data_val, batch_size, learning_rate, weight_decay=0, num_epochs=20):
    
    model = model.to(device)
    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    #criterion = nn.MSELoss()
    optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate, weight_decay=weight_decay)
    iters, losses, train_losses, test_losses = [], [], [], []
    iters_sub, train_acc, val_acc = [], [] ,[]
    print(batch_size)
    
    # weight sampler
    class0, class1 =labels_count(data_train)
    dataset_counts = [class0, class1]
    print(dataset_counts)
    num_samples = sum(dataset_counts)
    labels = [tag for _, tag in data_train]
    #max_value = max(input_list)
    #index = input_list.index(max_value)
    class_weights = [1./dataset_counts[i] for i in range(len(dataset_counts))]
    labels_indics = [i.index(max(i)) for i in labels ]
    weights = [class_weights[i] for i in labels_indics] # labels.max(1, keepdim=True)[1]
    weights = numpy.array(weights)
    samples_weight = torch.from_numpy(weights)
    samples_weigth = samples_weight.double()
    sampler = torch.utils.data.sampler.WeightedRandomSampler(samples_weight, int(num_samples), replacement=True)
    
    
    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        data_train,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        shuffle=False,
        sampler = sampler,
        collate_fn=lambda d: ([x[0] for x in d], [x[1] for x in d]),
        num_workers=os.cpu_count()//2
    )

    # training
    n = 0 # the number of iterations
    for epoch in tqdm(range(num_epochs), desc="epoch"):
        correct = 0
        total = 0
        for xs, ts in tqdm(train_loader, desc="train"):
            xs = torch.FloatTensor(xs).to(device)
            ts = torch.FloatTensor(ts).to(device)
            # print("batch index {}, 0/1: {}/{}".format(n,ts.tolist().count([1,0]),ts.tolist().count([0,1])))

            # if len(ts) != batch_size:
            #     print("ops")
            #     continue
            model.train()
            
            zs = model(xs)
            zs = zs.to(device)
            loss = criterion(zs, ts)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            optimizer.zero_grad()

            iters.append(n)
            loss.detach().cpu()
            
            losses.append(float(loss)/len(ts)) # compute *average* loss
            
            pred = zs.max(1, keepdim=True)[1] # get the index of the max logit
            target = ts.max(1, keepdim=True)[1]
            correct += pred.eq(target).sum().item()
            total += int(ts.shape[0])
            acc = correct / total

            if (n % len(train_loader) == 0) and n>0 and epoch%2==0:
                
                test_acc, test_loss = get_accuracy(model, data_val)
            
                iters_sub.append(n)
                train_acc.append(acc)
                val_acc.append(test_acc)
        
                train_losses.append(sum(losses)/len(losses))
                test_losses.append(test_loss)
                
                print("Epoch", epoch, "train_acc", acc)
                print("Epoch", epoch, "test_acc", test_acc)
                print("Epoch", epoch, "train_loss", sum(losses)/len(losses))
                print("Epoch", epoch, "test_loss", test_loss)

             # increment the iteration number
            n += 1
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), f"{MODEL_NAME}/checkpoint_epoch{epoch}.pt")


    # plotting
    plt.title("Training Curve (batch_size={}, lr={})".format(batch_size, learning_rate))
    plt.plot(iters_sub, train_losses, label="Train")
    plt.plot(iters_sub, test_losses, label="Test")
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.xlabel("Iterations")
    plt.ylabel("Loss")
    
    plt.savefig(f"{MODEL_NAME}/training_test_loss.png")
    
    # plt.show()
    plt.clf()
    plt.title("Training Curve (batch_size={}, lr={})".format(batch_size, learning_rate))
    plt.plot(iters_sub, train_acc, label="Train")
    plt.plot(iters_sub, val_acc, label="Test")
    plt.xlabel("Iterations")
    plt.ylabel("Accuracy")
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.savefig(f"{MODEL_NAME}/training_acc.png")
    #plt.show()
    return model
```

the main function

```
model = MyRegression(374, 2)
run_gradient_descent(
    model,
    training_set,
    test_set,
    batch_size= 64,  
    learning_rate=1e-2,
    num_epochs=200
)
```

Here is part of the training results so you can see that it is always decreasing

```
Epoch 2 train_acc 0.578125
Epoch 2 test_acc 0.7346171218510883
Epoch 2 train_loss 0.003494985813946325
Epoch 2 test_loss 0.00318981208993754
Epoch 4 train_acc 0.671875
Epoch 4 test_acc 0.7021743310868525
Epoch 4 train_loss 0.0034714722261212196
Epoch 4 test_loss 0.0033061892530283398
Epoch 6 train_acc 0.75
Epoch 6 test_acc 0.7614966302787455
Epoch 6 train_loss 0.003462064279302097
Epoch 6 test_loss 0.003087314312623757
Epoch 8 train_acc 0.625
Epoch 8 test_acc 0.7343577405202831
Epoch 8 train_loss 0.0034565126970269753
Epoch 8 test_loss 0.0032059013449951632
Epoch 10 train_acc 0.578125
Epoch 10 test_acc 0.7587194612023667
Epoch 10 train_loss 0.0034528369772701857
Epoch 10 test_loss 0.003112017690331294
Epoch 12 train_acc 0.65625
Epoch 12 test_acc 0.7097187501397528
Epoch 12 train_loss 0.003450584381555143
Epoch 12 test_loss 0.003285413007535127
Epoch 14 train_acc 0.578125
Epoch 14 test_acc 0.7509648538296759
Epoch 14 train_loss 0.0034486886994226553
Epoch 14 test_loss 0.003145160475069196
Epoch 16 train_acc 0.625
Epoch 16 test_acc 0.7629612403794123
Epoch 16 train_loss 0.0034474354597715125
Epoch 16 test_loss 0.003106232365138448
Epoch 18 train_acc 0.703125
Epoch 18 test_acc 0.7527134417666552
Epoch 18 train_loss 0.0034464063646294537
Epoch 18 test_loss 0.0031368749897371824
```

I tried to change different loss and also different models with different hyper parameters, but it is still the same case. I expect , maybe i am calculating the loss in wrong way.

Comment: Why is the loss decreasing a problem? That is exactly what you want....

Comment: yes it is decreasing for ever even when I increase the number of epochs, I do not know which epoch it converge?

Comment: That is something you have to find experimentally. In any case I do not see a programming problem here.

Comment: I did a lot of experiments even with different batchs and epoch , other hyper parameters but I see loss decrease on train data , change on test [decrease and increase]. I am wondering if there is something in my code. or something can make my model train faster than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Training loss continuing to go down if you train for more epochs is completely normal and expected. The training loss going down is just a sign that your model is fitting to the training data. Assuming that your model is large enough to capture the complexity of the data that you are training on, your training loss will eventually go down to zero, or at least close to zero.

What training loss *doesn't* tell you is how well your model will perform on unseen data. This is what your validation and/or test sets are for.

If your training loss continues to go down, but your test loss stops decreasing or starts increasing, then that's a sign that your model's performance has stopped improving. If you continue training past this point, your training loss will continue to go down, but you will just be overfitting to your training data, which could negatively affect your model's ability to make predictions on unseen data.

Try to train until the point where your test loss stops decreasing. You can use techniques like early stopping, or only saving model checkpoints when test loss goes down, to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

That is the goal of the training, minimize the loss. There's no problem about the training loss decreasing as long as it doesn't go below zero.

If you want to know when to stop the training, you can [EarlyStopping](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pytorch_lightning.callbacks.EarlyStopping.html#pytorch_lightning.callbacks.EarlyStopping).

About your model; you must use a classification model ie with a sigmoid (or softmax) activation function after the ouput layer. You also need activation functions between layers in order to make your model non-linear.

About your training function, when you compute the average loss, `losses.append(float(loss)/len(ts)) # compute *average* loss`, the loss is already the average loss over the batch, so you don't need to divide by `len(ts)` if it's average you want.

If what you want is the average loss over all batches at epoch `i`, it is

[image].